# Weak и unowned self

Tags: swift, best-practice

Потихоньку изучаю Swift и возник вопрос по weak и unowned self
К примеру, делаю какой-то запрос на сервер, что правильно использовать, weak или unowned?
Что если в closure этого запроса еще что-то делаю, ну пусть тоже еще один запрос, нужно ли снова писать [weak self]. Сферический пример в вакууме:

```
let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) { [weak self] //или unowned?
        (let location, let response, let error) in
    ...
    self?.error = error
    ...
    let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request1) { [weak self] // нужно ли снова писать?
        (let location, let response, let error) in
      ...
      self?.error1 = error
      ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

что лучше использовать weak или unowned?

Зависит от ситуации. я бы рекомендовал везде использовать weak, как более безопасный вариант. А в целом отличие вот такое:

> Use a weak reference whenever it is valid for that reference to become nil at some point during its lifetime. Conversely, use an unowned reference when you know that the reference will never be nil once it has been set during initialization.

2) weak self

Да, всегда надо использовать weak self. Если self (без weak) попадет в блок/closure это вызовет утечку памяти.

можете объявить weakSelf переменной, если вам так удобнее

```
weak var weakSelf = self
```

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 0):

`[weak self]` только в первом случае. Во втором не нужно, потому что self и так уже weak. Никакой утечки не будет.